# XAMPP, Apache server no longer works even after changing ports back

Tags: apache, xampp

I have been using XAMPP for months now without any issues.
But I wanted to change my ports so Skype would work while using XAMPP. Big mistake. I followed tutorials to change the ports correctly so **this** wouldn't happen. However after following the tutorial('s) the Apache server no longer works. So I thought: Well, okey no problem I'll just change them back to what they were (Port 80 and Port 433). But still Apache won't start and I'm out of ideas.

[XAMPP SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WANgc.png)

> **My Apache (httpd.conf)**
>
> ```
> Listen 80
>
> ServerName localhost:80
> ```
>
> **My Apache (httpd-ssl.conf)**
>
> ```
> Listen 443
>
> <VirtualHost _default_:443>
> ```

They are the same as before yet apache still won't run.

If you have any ideas of how I could fix this please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you pressed "the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues"?

Comment: Yes, they didn't tell me mucht though. But I have fixed it myself by asking a friend to send me his entire conf folder and I replaced mine with that one. Now my Apache works agian. Thanks though :)